# looking for inversed double values

Tags: c++, double-precision

I am looking for inverse double values

```
if( temp1.p[j] == -temp2.p[j] ) {
    cout << "Inverse Value \n";
}
```

Problem I have is that when I multiple the following value they are not always completely exact for instance the last 3 digits.

```
temp2.p[j] =   0.91217251125729792
-temp2.p[j] = -0.91217251124879162
```

Now I suspect it has something to do with the precision of doubles and the operation of sign bit but my question is what is the quickest solution?

I thought it would be easy to choose a precision of a double but this seems to only be the case when printing. So do I need to convert the values to strings in order to compare or is there a quicker method?

Comment: Floating-point numbers are inaccurate. To get around that, you need a different solution, depending on your exact needs. For example, checking if |x1-x2|<delta, or using fixed-point representation

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't believe the `temp2.p[j]` and `-temp2.p[j]` values you list could be output for a `double`s unless it was modified between the generation of those outputs; your values vary after only 10 significant digits, and double's normally good for at least 15 (and in this case where only the sign bit need be touched I'd expect most implementations to be precise). Please show us your actual code demonstrating a mismatch and high precision output for the values (e.g. with `std::fixed << std::setprecision(17)`).

Comment: great thanks for that, also sorry for duplication I did try a search and I could find what I was looking for.

Comment: @OphirGvirtzer `|x1-x2|<delta` is an oft-reached for hack but difficult to get right, as a good size fo the delta varies with the size of the "x" values. It's better to first use [`frexp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp) to normalise the values, then if the power-of-two values match you can apply your logic to the fraction knowing the order of magnitudes involved.

Comment: @Tony D Your improvement of the standard hack can be useful sometimes, but not always. think of (1.0/1e-8)*1e08 and  (1.0/1e-9)*1e09. The standard hack is useful in very restricted sections of code where the delta can be tailored to the expected values.

Comment: @OphirGvirtzer: quite so - I'm not saying "my" suggestion is "useful" or necessary *all* the time; my aim was just to warn readers that `|x1-x2|<delta` - which was presented as a solution *without qualification or caution* - is *often* flawed in a way that can be easily overlooked, and to simultaneously offer one of many more reliable approaches....